# how to check if all the variable not empty in PHP

Tags: php

I have to check weather all the variable are not empty
I'm using the following way.

```
if(empty($first_name) || 
   empty($last_name) || 
   empty($email) || 
   empty($password) || 
   empty($contact_no) || 
   empty($cnic)) {
    echo json_encode(array('condition' => 'error','data' => 'Please fill all inputs')); 
    exit;
}
```

The above code working but this looks bit odd. is there any shorter or more professional way to check all the inputs ? Ta

Comment: Use an array, count, filter, count.  And your not wanting to check if `All` are empty only if `Any` are empty, otherwise you would use and and not or.

Comment: You could create an own input validator class, for example using the strategy design pattern. I think it would be a more professional way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
$array = [
   'first_name' =>  'John',
    'last_name' => 'Doe',
    'email' => '',
];

if(count($array) != count(array_filter($array))){
    echo 'some rows are empty';
}
```

If you want to know which specific fields are empty you can use `array_diff_key`

```
$array = [
   'first_name' =>  'John',
    'last_name' => 'Doe',
    'email' => '',
];

$filled = array_filter($array);

if(count($array) != count($filled)){
    $empty = array_diff_key($array, $filled);
    echo 'field(s) '.implode(', ', array_keys($empty)).' are empty';
}
```

Ouputs:

```
field(s) email are empty
```

Obviously you can improve on the error string, or what have you.  So in your case I would do something like this

```
if(count($array) != count($filled)){
    $empty = array_keys(array_diff_key($array, $filled));
    $last = '';
    if(count($empty) > 1 ){
       $last = ' and '.array_pop($empty);
    }
    $fields = implode(', ', $empty).$last; 
    echo json_encode(array('condition' => 'error','data' => 'Please fill in '.$fields));
}
```

So it should output something like this:

```
Please fill in email

Please fill in first_name and email

Please fill in first_name, last_name and email
```

You could even do:

```
$empty = array_map(function($item){
   return ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $item));
}, $empty);
```

Which would take, `first_name` and change it to `First Name` if you want to get fancy.

So... Putting all that togather:

```
$array = [
   'first_name' =>  '',
    'last_name' => '',
    'email' => '',
];

$filled = array_filter($array);

if(count($array) != count($filled)){
    $empty = array_map(function($item){
        return ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $item));
    },array_keys(array_diff_key($array, $filled)));
    $last = '';
    if(count($empty) > 1 ){
       $last = " and '".array_pop($empty)."'";
    }
    $fields = "'".implode("', '", $empty)."'".$last; 
    echo json_encode(['condition' => 'error','data' => 'Please fill in '.$fields]);
}
```

Outputs:

```
{"condition":"error","data":"Please fill in 'First Name', 'Last Name' and 'Email'"}
```

You can see it [here live](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cf7207eb2e491c7033060d217de6639c43d2bf9e)

And now it tells them exactly what fields they need, instead of some generic error.

Comment: Sure, no problem

Comment: This unfortunately does not seem to work with `$_POST` as the array :\

Comment: No you will want to copy post to the array, so for example `$array  = $_POST` then go from there.  `$_POST` is a Super Global and may have some special considerations,

Answer (score 0):

You can either use an array for this purpose, or you can do an another approach on the same code like below.

```
if($first_name || $last_name || $email || $password || $contact_no || $cnic){
echo json_encode(array('condition' => 'error','data' => 'Please fill all inputs'));    
exit; }
```

**This will work because it is the same as checking empty of the variable.But will fail if the variable is not defined**

Comment: It's not the same, `$first_name` can throw an undefined variable, `empty($first_name)` won't issue that warning.  But otherwise it's basically the same.

Answer (score 0):

**isset() function**

The isset () function is used to check whether a variable is set or not. If a variable is already unset with unset() function, it will no longer be set. The isset() function return false if testing variable contains a NULL value.

> Version: (PHP 4 and above)

**Syntax:**

```
isset(variable1, variable2......)
```

In my option, we can do

```
if(isset($first_name,$last_name,$email,$password,$contact_no,$cnic) { 
   // true conditon
} else {
   // false condition 
}
```